# jQuery's $.ajax URL Encoding Problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, webkit, url-encoding

I'm using jQuery's $.ajax method to send and retrieve data to a REST service. Some of the URL's I'm providing to the $.ajax method requires spaces and other special characters to be encoded.

The problem lies with Chrome, Safari (Webkit) and Internet Explorer browsers. Firefox POST's to a URL which is encoded but the other browsers POST to a URL which isn't encoded.

As an example:

```
$.ajax ({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/123/Product Line A/[Product Type B]",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { ... },
  success: function(...){},
  error: function(...){}
})
```

Firefox POSTS the URL in the following format:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/123/Product%20Line%20A/%5BProduct%20Type%20B%5D
```

Chrome, Safari and IE POSTS the URL in the following format:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/123/Product Line A/[Product Type B]
```

The REST services accepts the encoded (Firefox) format - is there a way I can make this consistent across all browsers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use javascript's `encodeURI()` function to encode a URL into "Firefox format" as you state.

Answer (score 7):

Passing `[Product Type B]` in unencoded form is invalid, so what the browsers make of it is undefined.

Do a [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the product type part.

Comment: Is "Product Line B" also invalid? I'll give this a go the only problem it occurs and deeper and deeper levels just have to be careful I guess.

Comment: @schone yup, it is too. `encodeURI()` is more convenient because it allows you to run through the entire URL at once

Comment: `encodeURIComponent()` encodes `/` into `%2F`, which gives me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C` when used in the $.ajax url.

Answer (score 3):

I think .serialize() would be the jquery way to do this.

check here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

also there is a plugin for jquery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/URLEncode

or the javascript way ... encodeURIComponent()

check here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

Comment: When I tried encodeURIComponent() it seemed to encode the slashes as well which breaks the URL.

Comment: @schone  pass each component to `encodeURIComponent()` separately, then join them together with the slashes.  This is intentional and correct so that you can have a slash in the component and it will be encoded accordingly.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor there is Trusting and trusting, w3schools is good for the basics, sometimes much better than some unqualified comment on an answer on stackoverflow, see above.

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix would be to `encodeURI()` the URL before passing to $.ajax. You could also replace the $.ajax function with a thin wrapper to take the {} literal and encodeURI the URL before passing to the *original* function.